# Spring MVC form validation: missing model attribute object

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm having a strange problem handling form submission using Spring MVC.

I'm using Spring 3.1.1 and I'm implementing a simple form to insert/edit an entity into my DB.
My code is the following:

**JSP**

```
<sf:form action="save" method="post" modelAttribute="job">

    <sf:hidden path="id" />
    <span class="wrap">Label:</span> <sf:input path="label" />
    <sf:errors path="label"></sf:errors>

    <span class="wrap">Description:</span> <sf:textarea path="description" />
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
</sf:form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit")
public String editJob(Integer jobId, Model model) {
    ExportJob job = new ExportJob();
    if (jobId != null && jobId > 0) {
        job = schedulingService.getScheduledJob(jobId);
    }
    model.addAttribute("job", job);
    return VIEW_EDIT_FORM;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveJob(@ModelAttribute ExportJob job, BindingResult result) {

    ExportJobValidator ejValidator = new ExportJobValidator();
    ejValidator.validate(job, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return VIEW_EDIT_FORM;
    }
    schedulingService.saveAndSchedule(job);
    return "redirect:/schedule";
}
```

When model attribute validation fails I expect to be redirected to the form and the errors to be displayed. Instead I get this error:

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'job' available as request attribute`.

I tried passing the `job` in the `saveJob` method, but this way no error is shown...

I'm not an expert of Spring MVC, so can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a name of your model attribute that matches `modelAttribute` in `<form>`:

```
... @ModelAttribute("job") ExportJob job, ...
```

By default attribute name would be inferred from attribute's class name (`exportJob`), and it won't match `modelAttribute` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should show you errors that occur during databinding.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveJob(@ModelAttribute ExportJob job, BindingResult result, 
    ModelMap model) {

    //Debug errors, assumes logger is in place
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
       List<String> fieldErrors = new ArrayList<String>();
       for (FieldError f : result.getFieldErrors()) {
           fieldErrors.add(f.getField() + "=" + f.getRejectedValue().toString());
           log.debug("BindingFailure: {} = {}", new Object[] { f.getField(),
                 f.getRejectedValue() });
    }

    ExportJobValidator ejValidator = new ExportJobValidator();
    ejValidator.validate(job, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return VIEW_EDIT_FORM;
    }
    schedulingService.saveAndSchedule(job);
    return "redirect:/schedule";
}
```